# Problema ao fazer metodo POST no Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Estou com esse *body* para fazer um `POST` para o *backend*

```
'{"token":"xxxx", "extra_information": {"expires_in": xxxx, "refresh_token": "xxx", "user_id": "user_uuid", "token_type": "Bearer"}}'
```

Os parâmetros que estão com "xxxx" virão de uma integração, com isso, fiz uma função para isso.

```
func sendAuth() {
  if let url = NSURL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx"){
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST" 
    request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    let token = AccessToken?()
    let params = ["token" : (token?.tokenString)!, "refresh_token" : (token?.refreshToken)!,"expires_in" : (token?.expirationDate)!, "user_id" : "uber_uuid"  , "token_type" : "Bearer"] as Dictionary <String,AnyObject>

    let httpData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(params)
    request.HTTPBody = httpData
    let session = ServicesUtils.BaseSessionManager()
    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        var strData = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("\(strData)")
    }).resume()
```

Depois de ter feito os parâmetros corretamente o `xcode` esta aparecendo o seguinte erro:

> "Cannot convert value of type 'NSURLResponse to expected argument type 'NSData"

Alguém poderia me ajudar com esse problema?

Acredito que seja na linha `let httpData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(params)` que o erro se inicia mas não sei como fazer outra sintaxe para funcionar o código .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não especificou a versão do seu Xcode eu vou responder com o código para a versão atual do App Store (Xcode 8.2.1 • Swift 3.0.2). Coloquei os commentários sobre os problemas e soluções do seu código a seguir:

```
func sendAuth() {
    // Swift 3 voce deve usar URL em vez de NSURL
    if let url = URL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx") {
        // e em vez de NSMutableURLRequest voce deve usar URLRequest declarando como variavel
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        // voce deve usar JSONSerialization para converter o seu JSON object para Data
        let jsonObject = ["token" : "Token String", "refresh_token" : "refresh_token String","expires_in" : "expires_in String", "user_id" : "uber_uuid", "token_type" : "Bearer"]
        request.httpBody = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: jsonObject)
        // e usar URLSession em vez de NSURL Session
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let data = data,   // unwrap data
                error == nil,      // se nao houver error
                (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200   // e status code for igual a 200
            else {
                print((response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? "no status code")
                print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no error description")
                return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) ?? "no string from data")
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

Se você ainda estiver usando Swift 2 eu recomendo você atualizar o seu Xcode para a versão mais recente baixando o Xcode novo do AppStore.

Caso você não possa atualizar o seu Xcode no momento, segue o codigo para Swift 2:

```
func sendAuth() {
    if let url = NSURL(string: "https://xxxxxxxxxxxx") {
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
        request.setValue("application/json; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        // voce deve usar NSJSONSerialization para converter o seu JSON object para Data
        let jsonObject = ["token" : "Token String", "refresh_token" : "refresh_token String","expires_in" : "expires_in String", "user_id" : "uber_uuid", "token_type" : "Bearer"]
        request.HTTPBody = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(jsonObject, options: [])
        NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
            guard
                let data = data where   // unwrap data
                error == nil &&      // se nao houver error
                (response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode == 200   // e status code for igual a 200
                else {
                    print((response as? NSHTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode ?? "no status code")
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "no error description")
                    return
            }
            print(String(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) ?? "no string from data")
            }.resume()
    }
}
```

Comment: obrigado pela resposta ;) . Só uma duvida: no jsonObject eu precisaria passar os dados que estao na instancia `let  token = AcessToken()` fazendo do jeito que voce respondeu daria para ser feito o POST sem passar esses dados?

Comment: @Annihilatorz eu só coloquei uma String qualquer pro exemplo, lógico que você precisa colocar o valor do seu token String no dicionário. Não esquece de unwrap o valor usando if let.